# 'Series' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataframe data['6EF3'] with a column named 'Time' (type datetime64[ns]). I would like to calculate the delta time since the first time stamp in that column, so my code is
`data['6EF3']['t']=(data['6EF3']['Time']-data['6EF3'].loc[0,'Time'])`

[the output is as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2S5J.png)

I want to use the delta time for other calculations, but I'm aware that column 't' is of type timedelta64[ns] and cannot be used in operations like division. So I wanted to change the data in column 't' to type float64. I used the code below

`data['6EF3']['t']=(data['6EF3']['Time']-data['6EF3'].loc[0,'Time']).timestamp()`

but I got an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'timestamp'.

I wonder if there is a simple way to achieve what I was describing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [total_seconds](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) from the series to convert from `timedelta64` to float:

```
data['6EF3']['t'] = (data['6EF3']['Time']-data['6EF3'].loc[0,'Time']).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, you can provide an upvote if you found this useful.